# copy entire response of soap request as an argument in another request

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, groovy, soapui

I want to copy the tags/body between the "return" "\return" into a subsequent soap request as an argument between "arg1" "/arg1" using groovy scripting.

I tried to parameterize each tag but its difficult to do so and wanted to know if there is any way out to copy the entire body between "return" and "\return".

Not sure if my question make sense but I am new to Stack-overflow and would like to learn soapui and groovy.

Response of my request is as below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getxyz1Response xmlns:ns2="xyz.com">
         <return>
            <xyz1>70</xyz1>
            <balance>33.0000000000</balance>
            <carriedBalance>0E-10</carriedBalance>
            <createDatetime>2017-08-09T00:00:00Z</createDatetime>
            <createTimeStamp>2017-08-09T22:48:24.423Z</createTimeStamp>
            <currencyId>1</currencyId>
            <deleted>0</deleted>
            <dueDate>2017-08-09T00:00:00Z</dueDate>
            <id>43194</id>
            <xyz1>1</xyz1>
            <xyz1>
               <amount>10.0000343500</amount>
               <amountAsDecimal>10.0000343500</amountAsDecimal>
               <callCounter>0</callCounter>
               <deleted>0</deleted>
               <description>testCategory90795 Period from 30/03/2017 to 29/04/2017</description>
               <id>113492</id>
               <itemId>220</itemId>
               <percentage>0</percentage>
               <price>10.0000343500</price>
               <priceAsDecimal>10.0000343500</priceAsDecimal>
               <quantity>1.0000000000</quantity>
               <quantityAsDecimal>1.0000000000</quantityAsDecimal>
               <sourcexyz1Id>22143</sourcexyz1Id>
            </xyz1>
            <xyz1>
               <amount>10.0000343500</amount>
               <amountAsDecimal>10.0000343500</amountAsDecimal>
               <callCounter>0</callCounter>
               <deleted>0</deleted>
               <description>testCategory90795 Period from 30/04/2017 to 29/05/2017</description>
               <id>113493</id>
               <itemId>220</itemId>
               <percentage>0</percentage>
               <price>10.0000343500</price>
               <priceAsDecimal>10.0000343500</priceAsDecimal>
               <quantity>1.0000000000</quantity>
               <quantityAsDecimal>1.0000000000</quantityAsDecimal>
               <sourcexyz1Id>22143</sourcexyz1Id>
            </xyz1>
            <xyz1>
               <amount>10.0000343500</amount>
               <amountAsDecimal>10.0000343500</amountAsDecimal>
               <callCounter>0</callCounter>
               <deleted>0</deleted>
               <description>testCategory90795 Period from 30/05/2017 to 29/06/2017</description>
               <id>113494</id>
               <itemId>220</itemId>
               <percentage>0</percentage>
               <price>10.0000343500</price>
               <priceAsDecimal>10.0000343500</priceAsDecimal>
               <quantity>1.0000000000</quantity>
               <quantityAsDecimal>1.0000000000</quantityAsDecimal>
               <sourcexyz1Id>22143</sourcexyz1Id>
            </xyz1>
            <xyz1>
               <amount>3.0000103050</amount>
               <amountAsDecimal>3.0000103050</amountAsDecimal>
               <callCounter>0</callCounter>
               <deleted>0</deleted>
               <description>GST</description>
               <id>113495</id>
               <itemId>45</itemId>
               <percentage>0</percentage>
               <price>10.0000000000</price>
               <priceAsDecimal>10.0000000000</priceAsDecimal>
               <quantity>1.0000000000</quantity>
               <quantityAsDecimal>1.0000000000</quantityAsDecimal>
               <sourcexyz1Id>22143</sourcexyz1Id>
            </xyz1>
            <isReview>0</isReview>
            <number>40677</number>
            <orders>44652</orders>
            <xyz1Attempts>0</xyz1Attempts>
            <statusDescr>Unpaid</statusDescr>
            <statusId>2</statusId>
            <toProcess>1</toProcess>
            <total>33.0000000000</total>
            <xyz1Id>22143</xyz1Id>
         </return>
      </ns2:getxyz1Response>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

1/ You need to retrieve XML from source testStep (named 'SOAP Request' in example below) and target the 'return' node.

```
def sourceTCresponse = context.expand('${SOAP Request#Response}')
def sourceTCresponse_XML = new XmlParser().parseText(sourceTCresponse)
def targetNode = sourceTCresponse_XML.'**'.find {it.name() == 'return'}
```

2/ You need to retrieve XML from you target testStep (named 'SOAP Request2' in example below)

```
def targetTestStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["SOAP Request2"]
def targetTestStep_Request = targetTestStep.getPropertyValue("Request")
def targetTC_XML = new XmlParser().parseText(targetTestStep_Request)
```

3/ Then append the node from 1/ to the arg1 node from 2/

```
targetTC_XML.'**'.find {it.name() == 'arg1'}.append(targetNode)
```

4/ Then convert final XML to a string

```
def xmlOutput = new StringWriter()
def xmlNodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(xmlOutput))
xmlNodePrinter.print(targetTC_XML)
String finalXML_asString = xmlOutput.toString()
```

5/ Then write this string into your target test step

```
targetTestStep.setPropertyValue("Request", finalXML_asString)`
```